# Как создать класс формы Qt в Visual Studio C++?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, qt5

Как в Visual Studio создать класс формы Qt (C++ Qt5)? В доступных файлах я нашла только `.ui` файл:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если создать такой, то для него ведь нужно ещё отдельно создавать `MainWindow.h` и `MainWindow.cpp`. И как получить доступ к элементам, созданным в конструкторе форм? Например для установки текста:

```
ui->label_2->setText("text");
```

Где `ui`:

```
private:
    Ui::MainWindow ui;
};
```

Такой код выдаёт ошибку `выражение должно иметь тип указателя`.

Comment: это плохой путь, плагины для VS. Лучше проект изменять в QtCreator, а потом делать из pro-файла проект для VS: "qmake -t vcapp".
Там можно создать сразу три файла cpp, h, ui

Answer (score 1, accepted):

в хедере:

```
private:
    Ui::MainWindow* ui;
};
```

в конструкторе:

```
Widget::Widget(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow )
{
    ui->setupUi(this)
}
```